# How to load BufferedImage in android?

Tags: android, bufferedimage

I want to load `BufferedImage` in my application. For that I am using `ImageIO` but I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
BufferedImage tgtImg = loadImage("ImageD2.jpg"); 
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String ref) { 
    BufferedImage bimg = null; 
    try { 
        bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(ref)); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return bimg; 
}
```

but i am getting exception:

```
03-15 18:05:22.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.imageio.ImageIO
```

Comment: I am trying to load bufferedimage as :'

BufferedImage tgtImg = loadImage("ImageD2.jpg");

public static BufferedImage loadImage(String ref) { BufferedImage bimg = null; try { bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(ref)); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } return bimg; }

but i am getting exception :

03-15 18:05:22.051: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.imageio.ImageIO

Please help me

Comment: @user437833, you should _edit_ your _question_, by _edit_ not _answer_. By the way, put 4 spaces before a line will make it _code_. You can see that effect in the preview.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK

Could you achieve the same thing with [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)?? like so...

```
Bitmap tgtImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("ImageD2.jpg");
```

if `tgtImg` is not `null` after this then it was successful.