# How to read png images form inputstream in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, remote-desktop

There are 2 applications. One application act as server and sends continuously screen shot of desktop  by using the following code.

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
OutputStream os;
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
```

The second application is Android application acts a client application and has to read continuously the above image stream from inputstream.

Could please help me to read the png images from inputstream in the client application.

Thanks & Regards
Mini.

Comment: there is `ImageIO.read(InpusTream)` too ;), you can write (as you do) and read...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312288/561543

Comment: is there any way to read the png image header without using the java.awt.* package and javax.imageIo.* ?

Answer (score 2):

In *client* application, read the InputStream via `Socket.getInputStream()` method.

```
 BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: Here I am not using the java.awt package

Comment: As `ImageIO` will wrap the stream in an `ImageInputStream` I doubt that the added `BufferedInputStream` will be of much use.

Comment: The Application thread is hanging at this line BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); Since the server sends the imagestream continously to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK does not support the method ImageIO.read(). Even if you can compile your code, your android application will get crashed and have error about missing libraries like this:

> could not find method javax.imageio.imageio.read

What I suggest is using bitmapping instead of this...