# How to improve image quality for OCR reader in Android

Tags: android

I've made an app which uses the phone's camera to take a photo and then parses this photo (with Tesseract OCR) into a string.

The problem is that the string I obtain is very ugly, it contains wrong or unreadable characters.

I've read [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) that a filter to reduce image's noise may improve OCR's result. I've googled some of them and I've found [this website](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) which contains a lot of image filters written in Java. The issue is that they use `BufferedImage` class, which is not in Android SDK.

Does anyone know any other library which performs this operation in android?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bitmap. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

It's the equivalent (in theory, not in api) with BufferedImage.

Chek this post too:
[How to load BufferedImage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311163/how-to-load-bufferedimage-in-android)

Comment: it doesn't work because the noise filter method that I've found requires a `BufferedImage` to work.

Comment: yes, I have access to the code, but there are many things that I don't know if they are easily portable in android, such as `WritableRaster`, `BufferedImageOp`, and many others classes.

Comment: Take a look at this thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210065/how-can-i-import-java-awt-image-bufferedimage-in-android-studio . Unfortunately, you need to make some changes in order to work in Android